# Observable Network IO Parsing

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to use Rx to read from a TCPClient receive stream and parse the data into an IObservable of string, delimited by newline "\r\n"  The following is how I'm receiving from the socket stream...

```
var messages = new Subject<string>();

var functionReceiveSocketData =
            Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, SocketFlags, int>
            (client.Client.BeginReceive, client.Client.EndReceive);

Func<byte[], int, byte[]> copy = (bs, n) =>
        {
            var rs = new byte[buffer.Length];
            bs.CopyTo(rs, 0);
            return rs;
        };

Observable
    .Defer(() =>
            {
                var buffer = new byte[50];
                return
                    from n in functionReceiveSocketData(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None)
                select copy(buffer, n);
            }).Repeat().Subscribe(x => messages.OnNext(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x)));
```

Here is what I came up with to parse the string.  This currently does not work...

```
obsStrings = messages.Buffer<string,string>(() =>  
                messages.Scan((a, c) => a + c).SkipWhile(a => !a.Contains("\r\n"))
            );
```

The message subject receives the message in chunks so I'm trying to concat them and test whether the concatenated string contains newline, thus signaling the buffer to close and output the buffered chunks.  Not sure why it isn't working.  Seems that I only get the first chunk out of obsStrings.

So I am looking for two things.  I'd like to simplify reading of the io stream and eliminate the use of the messages subject.  Secondly, I'd like to get my string parsing working.  I have been hacking on this for a bit and cannot come up with a working solution.  I am a beginner with Rx.

**EDIT:  Here is the finished product after the problem was solved....**

```
var receivedStrings = socket.ReceiveUntilCompleted(SocketFlags.None)
            .SelectMany(x => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x).ToCharArray())
            .Scan(String.Empty, (a, b) => (a.EndsWith("\r\n") ? "" : a) + b)
            .Where(x => x.EndsWith("\r\n"))
            .Select(buffered => String.Join("", buffered))
            .Select(a => a.Replace("\n", ""));
```

"ReceiveUntilCompleted" is an extension from the RXX project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
messages
    .Scan(String.Empty, (a, b) => (a.EndsWith("\r\n") ? "" : a) + b)
    .Where(x => x.EndsWith("\r\n"))
```

Comment: I found that I didn't need the .Buffer(1); at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Subscribe` and using the `Subject`, can you try just `Select`:

`.Repeat().Select(x => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x));`

Now assuming this has all gone into a new observable called `messages`, your next problem is that in this line

```
var obsStrings = messages.Buffer<string,string>(() =>  
                messages.Scan((a, c) => a + c).SkipWhile(a => !a.Contains("\r\n"))
            );
```

You're using both `Buffer` and `Scan`, and are trying to do the same thing in both! Note that `Buffer` needs a closing selector.

What you really want is:

```
var obsStrings = messages.Buffer(() => messages.Where(x => x.Contains("\r\n")))
                         .Select(buffered => String.Join(buffered));
```

Which gives Buffered an observable regarding when to close the window (when it contains \r\n) and gives Select the buffered amount to concatenate. This results in a new observable of your split strings.

One issue is that you can still have the new line in the middle of a chunk and this will cause problems. One simple idea is to observe on the characters rather than full string chunks, such as:

`obsStrings.Repeat().SelectMany(x => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x).ToCharArray().ToObservable());`

Then you can do `messages.Where(c => c != '\r')` to skip `\r` and change the buffer to:

```
var obsStrings = messages.Buffer(() => messages.Where(x => x == '\n')))
                         .Select(buffered => String.Join("", buffered));
```

Comment: Think you want `messages.Where(x => x == '\n')` not `messages.Where(x => x != '\n')` in the `Buffer` call. That is, it will break the buffer on every new line.

Comment: Still getting disjointed chunks out of this oberservable.  I wonder if it's a threading issue where the testing is being done on another thread and the buffering continues or breaks early so the buffering becomes indeterminate.

Comment: The `Buffer` command won't break early, it's not time based or anything like that. Hard to know how to help without more info, or an example of what 'breaking' looks like.